# How do I pull from a git repo on a remote machine through ssh?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, gitlab

I have several remote machines that need to pull from a repo after I've completed testing and ready to make updates to production (python Flask app and supporting classes). A couple of the machines need to pull from a different branch, as well. I've been SSHing to each machine to run the git pull, but this is getting annoying and time consuming.

I'm trying to run an ssh command that completes a git pull. This is what I've tried:

```
ssh dev@<remote IP> "cd /home/dev/<repo> && git pull"
```

And I'm getting a

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I'm able to run other git commands just fine that don't interact with remote origin. Such as:

```
ssh dev@<remote IP> "cd /home/dev/<repo> && git remote -v"
```

When I actually ssh on to the remote machine. I have no problem navigating to the directory and running a **git pull**.

I also made sure that I added the ssh key to an ssh-agent so that password prompts on the key wouldn't be an issue.

Thought it could potentially be a key permissions issue, so I double checked that the key is readable by the user I'm running the command as.

It's frustrating that I am able to ssh on to the remote machine and run the pull just fine, but cannot run the command with the format above.

Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: Your error message definitely suggests that ssh is unable to log in when it's invoked through git, although I can't tell why that would be the case.

Comment: How do you authenticate to the git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood with your issue, here is my suggestion : 
[ Information is somewhat incomplete though ]

GIT reads your id_rsa.pub in root user directory : /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

That's why your key in /home/your_username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub might not be read by git.

Hence, please check and create the key in /home/root/.ssh/

```
$ sudo su
$ ssh-keygen
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ cat id_rsa.pub
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Had a root key paid and it still didn't work out. Oddly enough, I'm able to ssh both as root and the user to complete the git pull, but this remote command is just not working out. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-A` option.

`ssh -A dev@<remote IP> "cd /home/dev/<repo> && git pull"`

I ran across the option in a comment here when trying to find the answer to this problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/762983/ssh-and-git-pull-from-remote-server

From https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh:

> If the ForwardAgent variable is set to ''yes'' (or see the description of the -A and -a options above) and the user is using an authentication agent, the connection to the agent is automatically forwarded to the remote side.